# Outlook open recurring item dialog box not displayed for some users

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

My predecessor created recurring meetings for our team.  The title of the recurring meetings is "Available".  When a member needs a specific occurrence of the meeting (let's say next monday) it will change the the title of this specific occurrence to "Reserved".  This way the team can schedule the subjects of our meeting.

Here's the problem, usually when you click on one of a recurring meetings, the "Open recurring item dialog box"  will show up.    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iBqt.png

```
  I Don't have enough reputation on this site to post pictures.  
  So the popup   is the one displaying :  
  "*This is one appointement in a series.  What do you want to open? "* 
  And then 2 radio buttons *"Just this one"* or "*The entire series*"
```

So the problem being that for some users this popup will not showup and they can't choose to modify a single instance.    The end result being since they can't choose to modify only one occurrence, the whole series is being modified.

Does someone can explain to me why this is acting this way for some users and can this be fixed easily?  I'm not a real super geek so I'll appreciate if you could explain in simple terms if possible.

Many thanks in advance for any help provided

Comment: How about right clicking a single occurrence of the meeting to see if it can be opened via Open > Open Occurrence?

Comment: Thanks Yuki Sun for the suggestion.  I've modify my questions to improve the clarity of it.  So yes, the user can open via right click and choose "one occurrence"  but it's not ideal, since I'd have to educate all users.  Since the problem is only for some meetings in a shared calendar I'd prefer to fix the bug.  Tx for any other thoughts you could have on this.